# How to add new contacts to an outlook.com account in an Android device?

Tags: contacts, outlook.com

My contacts are all stored in an outlook.com account and I would like to continue storing them there. To access and use these contacts (say to make a phone call), from my Google Pixel device, I have my outlook.com account added to the phone settings > accounts.

This works as it should. All my outlook accounts are accessible from my phone.

When I want to create and save a new contact, the options exist to create the contact from Google's Phone App and the Contacts App. When I click save, to save the contact, the contact doesn't get saved. No indication is given that the contact is not saved. Only when I check my list of contacts do I know the contact is not saved.

Is there any other way to save a contact to outlook.com from an android device?
Alternatively, does the above method I use to save contacts from Google's phone or contacts app work for any one else?

The current workaround I use is to visit the outlook.com website using a web browser, and then create and save new contacts. When Android periodically syncs the contacts, I get to see the new contacts on my phone. This workaround usually works better if the desktop version of outlook.com is used. The mobile version is not very friendly for saving new contacts to outlook.com.

Answer (score 1):

There is another workaround which involves a handy third-party tool- [Contact Editor Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.android.contacts&hl=en).

> This editor is a replacement/alternative for your native editor and
>   it's invoked in the same way. It will be started whenever you try to
>   edit or create a contact (and you select "Contact Editor Free")

When you use the regular Contacts app to create a new contact, it gives you the alternative option to use this application, which gives you the option to add either a gmail.com or **outlook.com contact** essentially overcoming android's limitation to add outlook contacts.

One user mentions a minor drawback:

> The only drawback to the Contact Editor Free solution that I've found
>   is that I can't delete contacts from the outlook.com account this way.
>   That's a pretty minor problem, however, since deleting contacts is
>   something I do a lot less often than adding them.

Acknowledgements

- [How to add contacts to my outlook.com account](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-to-add-contacts-to-my-outlook-com-account.274874/)

Comment: Did the workaround solve your issue?

Comment: I'll try it over the weekend. The app seems promising. Although its interface is quite dull. Thanks for your help.